# Unable to load the manifest designer, PhonePublisherId is missing

Tags: winui-3

After associating with Microsoft Store, when I open the Manifest, it doesn't open. and shows this error. What doest it mean? How to correct this? I have never encountered such an error with UWP apps, while opening the manifest. It's weird. I am using Visual Studio 2022, Version 17.0.5.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Right click Package.appxmanifest

View Code

remove <mp:PhoneIdentity ...../>

[image]